# How can I find some type of objects via OSM

Tags: json, get, openstreetmap

How can i find some type of object via OpenStreetMap ? I want to send the request and receive answer in XML format (JSON will be ok). E.g. i want to know what historical objects or restaurant are available in place where I'm.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to query for OSM data and [Overpass Turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) for testing/displaying.

For more infos you should checkout the OSM specific sites: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Help

Comment: I saw this but i don't know how to use it. I found tons of useless information but I just need the simple example with request to find some object, nothing more.

Comment: For using the Overpass API you will need to have an idea about [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in OSM, or try the wizard of overpass turbo.

Answer (score 1):

For simple queries a geocoder should suffice. There are various [search engines for OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) of which [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is the most popular one currently. Please see [Nominatim's usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) if you intend to use OpenStreetMap's official Nominatim instance, or choose one of the [alternatives](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers).

For more complex queries take a look at the Overpass API mentioned in the [answer by RoToRa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27780158/1340631).